# Why is destructuring an array in javascript slower than for an object?

Tags: javascript, optimization, v8, destructuring, micro-optimization

I have ran a few different variations of this, but this is the basic test that I have made on jsbench.me:

https://jsbench.me/j2klgojvih/1

This initial benchmark has an obvious initial optimization that makes the object destructure significantly faster. If you move the declaration of t into each test block, that underlying optimization disappears, but the array destructure still loses.

The test is a simple concept represented by:

```
const t = [1, 2, 3];

// Test 1 (Slower)
const [x, y, z] = t;

// Test 2 (Faster)
const {0: x, 1: y, 2: z} = t;
```

I would think V8 (or any JS engine) could/should run the array destructuring faster; however, I have not been able to make a variation of the test where that is the case.

If I were to poke a guess at the reasoning, it'd be that array destructuring runs some iterator to loop through the array.

Comment: Without trawling [though the code base](https://github.com/v8/v8). I'd imagine this is due to property access being `O(1)` and array access being `O(1-n)`. *.... array destructuring runs some iterator to loop through the array* well yes, how else do you think it would access the array?

Comment: they said they've optimized the React pattern but that's up to 2 properties, no more than 2. Destructuring arrays means being sure the `length` boundary is preserved, there is an iteration dance behind, and so on. Destructuring object properties means directly accessing the object and assign whatever value is there. If you can think of any way to do this via code, the latter case is just const x = t[0], const y = t[1], and const z = t[2] ... the right hand side doesn't need to be iterated, or inspected, too much.

Comment: @Liam I would expect a set number of array property access would be able to NOT use an iterative approach. I mean, the compiler sees exactly how many properties are going to be retrieved, it could essentially create the object destructure pattern for you in its place. WHY would you iterate for statically known properties?

Comment: This all smells of micro optimisation. Yes, in that test this is slowER. But it's probably fast enough for 99% of scenarios. So what's the developers incentive to make this faster? There are more important features to implement

Comment: @Liam I am definitely asking this for the purpose of micro-optimization. This isn't a line of questioning for 99% of JS devs :) I'm working on some items that are pushing JS limits pretty stinken hard.

Comment: Ok, so taking that for granted, what's your question? why, because it is. Adding a question here isn't going to make this any faster so I'm struggling to understand what your hoping to gain here?

Comment: You have to remember that Node is just a port of the chrome engine. It's not designed to be incredibly performant and in fact has some well known performance issue. If this is really a big problem and you really want speed, node is probably the wrong language choice. Running on a windows machine Native is ALWAYS going to be the choice for speed

Comment: It's not in Node, it's in the browser. I didn't ask my question to debate the merits of my tech stack. I just want understanding on the "why" because some micro optimizations get tweaked and modified by the underlying engine rendering the optimization pointless after a minor engine update. Whereas some optimizations are useful because there's a very good and unmoving reason why the underlying engine chose to do so. So, I'm looking to see if this is likely to remain steady for a long time, or if it's something just not addressed yet.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

(V8 developer here.)

> If I were to poke a guess at the reasoning, it'd be that array destructuring runs some iterator to loop through the array.

Yup. [The spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation) pretty much demands it that way.

> WHY would you iterate for statically known properties?

In JavaScript, significantly fewer things are "statically known" than it might seem at first. And even if they're statically derivable in a microbenchmark, that might not be enough reason to optimize for them, because real-world code tends to be a lot more complicated.

> I am definitely asking this for the purpose of micro-optimization.

Be aware that microbenchmarks are usually misleading, even for micro-optimizations. If you real use-case is different from the benchmark, then the benchmark's results are very likely not going to be representative, and as such may well lead you to wasting time on things that don't help or are even counter-productive.

In this particular case, I have no reason to doubt that array destructuring will likely be somewhat slower than object destructuring regardless of circumstances; but the relative difference and hence whether it matters depend a lot on the situation (factors such as: function size, call count, inlineability, are the results used or ignored, are the inputs constant or changing, ...).

> So, I'm looking to see if this is likely to remain steady for a long time, or if it's something just not addressed yet.

I don't know whether there is much untapped performance potential in array destructuring, nor whether/when someone might look into it.

> It's not designed to be incredibly performant

Oh, yes, it is; and we keep working hard to make it even more performant.

Comment: Appreciate the response :) Confirmation of the iteration and link to the spec definitely resolved my question. And yes, I generally try to be careful of being caught in special case optimizations in benchmarks...I ran a heckuva lot more tests than indicated before deciding I really was seeing a performance difference. It's definitely a silly thing to investigate, but I enjoy looking into this stuff. Thanks for your work on v8!